# Table data analyzer

Tags: logging, analysis

I have big file that contains log information. Suppose, it in CSV format and has table structure. 
I want tool that can load this file and make some queries. For example:  show often repeated entries, count of same entries  etc.

Answer (score 1):

'excel' comes to mind. otherwise ['r'](http://www.r-project.org/), the language for statistical computing, especially ['importing spreadsheet like data'](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html#Spreadsheet_002dlike-data) is worth reading.

Comment: file contains thousands of records so excel doesn't match and visual tool will preferred.

Comment: excel is capable of displaying 32k rows ...

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Access

Comment: Didn't find how to import data

Comment: Look harder. :)  Try opening the csv file with Access.

Answer (score 1):

Try Microsoft's [Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en). Some more info [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000369.html), and a GUI for it [here](http://www.codeplex.com/visuallogparser).

Answer (score 0):

Excel is your best bet. I agree with @akira

Access is too complicated for this task. You would have to mess around with wizards and not quite get what you want or figure out SQL

Excel is more than enough 'visual'. You can make pivots and charts to get a better sense of your data